# {ItemId} is null in SharePoint Custom Ribbon Action

Tags: sharepoint-2010

As the title says, the {ItemId} is null for the code listed below.  I read on a blog that the tokens may not be implemented in the Custom Ribbon Action.  Can anyone confirm this?

Please take a look at my Elements.xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <CustomAction ScriptSrc="ADBTicketing/scripts/CustomActions.js" Location="ScriptLink" RegistrationType="List" RegistrationId="12000"></CustomAction>
      <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.AddAButton.ADBServices.EmailStatus"
                    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" RegistrationType="List" RegistrationId="12000">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.ADBServices.EmailStatus"
              Command="EmailStatusOfItem"
              Image32by32="/_layouts/Images/ADBTicketing/EmailClient.png"
              LabelText="E-mail Status"
              Sequence="21"
              TemplateAlias="o1"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="EmailStatusOfItem"
                      CommandAction="javascript:addCommentToTicket({ItemId});"></CommandUIHandler>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Thanks,
Joshua

Answer (score 4):

In the View Ribbon use

```
SelectedItemId
```

instead of

```
ItemId
```

Comment: This spared me too. Fwiw, I was then able to access that value on the server side by following some code snips here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=203

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in CommandAction, but not in EnabledScript as I'm finding out...

So for yours to work you pass to javascript and surround with single quotes as:
CommandAction="javascript:addCommentToTicket('{ItemId}');"